# pynput.keyboard terminate program when key is pressed not responding

Tags: keyboard, pynput

I have this code here and what I want is for the code to type "potato" every 5 seconds. I also want a "quit" command, and I want it so that when I press `=` it will stop the program. However, not only does the code not work, but it also types "=" after it types/enters "potato". Can someone help? Thanks.

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(3)

while True:
  keyboard.type('potato')
  keyboard.press(Key.enter)
  keyboard.release(Key.enter)
  if keyboard.type('asdf'):
    quit()
  time.sleep(5)
```

P.S. no errors or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious answer here would be to change the "asdf" to "=" in the `if` statement, but if that doesn't fix the problem, you could add a listener to detect keypresses.

```py
from pynput import keyboard, Key, Controller
import time

# set your termination key here
cut_key = "="

# check if key pressed is cut_key, if so, quit
def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key.char == cut_key:
            quit()
    except AttributeError:
        if key == cut_key:
            quit()

# non-blocking listener
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(3)

while True:
    keyboard.type('potato')
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I didn't test this code, please comment if it doesn't work.
https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html